# is it possible to save effected image from gl-react-native?

Tags: opengl-es, react-native

https://github.com/ProjectSeptemberInc/gl-react-native/issues/116

I am using gl-react-native to create some awesome image effects, my question is how to save these effected images into new images, since gl-react-native just create a filter layer on the original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, there is a way to capture the Surface view.

checkout this documentation: https://projectseptemberinc.gitbooks.io/gl-react/content/docs/api/Surface.html

for instance:

in your render:

`<Surface ref="surface">{...}</Surface>`

and later

`this.refs.surface.captureFrame({ type: "png", format: "file" }).then(uri => {
  console.log("DO SOMETHING WITH", uri);
});`

Comment: How can I save an image without rendering?